# Select2 in WordPress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I have seen some best practices in WordPress about enqueueing scripts in WordPress. The scripts that are already in WordPress core should not be added again, but call that from WordPress core. I want to know whether `select2` is in WordPress core. I have found only one article saying so
[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/2vfqpo/using_select2_from_wp_core/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not. They may have been planning it for 4.1 or 4.2, as suggested in your link, but for whatever reason it never happened.

You can see a list of core-registered scripts that you include [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/#core-registered-scripts).

Another thing to keep in mind is that many (arguably *too* many) plugins enqueue their own version of the script, so be aware of potential conflicts.

Comment: Doesn't woocommerce enqueue one ? So can we use that if the plugin completely rely on woocommerce ?

Comment: Yes, probably. Although I believe WooCommerce has essentially forked it to create their own version: https://github.com/woocommerce/selectWoo So you'd use that.